# Migrate from Titanium to React native

Tags: react-native, migration, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have been working in an enterprise app created with titanium SDK, specifically with Alloy, we have been facing that the community and tooling of titanium are quite a few, we are feeling all the time that we are stuck with this technology, so our team have seen in some blogs that they used to talk about titanium SDK that they have been migrated their complete projects to RN, but there is not any manual to do it, so I'm looking for a general recipe o at least a road map to make the migration and have a better idea about the implications.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Follow [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) link to setup and create react native project. Migrate wot be possible i guess.

Comment: Ok, I understand that maybe there is no chance to migrate all the layers, like the UI layer, but what about the business logic, is written totally in JS with ECMAScript 5, there is a chance to do it? or even this logic will have a strong refactoring? Thanks.

Comment: that depends on your business layer and how tightly it uses Titanium features. Since all titanium features will have to be manually written to a react native counterpart. BTW I feel you, I bet there are many more companies stuck with this framework that is so full of bugs. At the time (5y ago) it was a viable option for cross-platform apps but I feel like today it cant compete with frameworks that can properly use npm and actually compile fast.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are some companies still stuck with this outdated and buggy technology, however, I don't want to turn this question into a complain, the migration seems really hard to accomplish, but we have to do it, otherwise we can not beat other competitors in the market, I'm still trying, if I have success with this task I will come with some useful info :D

Comment: @dicarlomagnus any success with your project to migrate titanium to RN?

Comment: @jagger, short story: No we couldn't, after several sprints and a couple of millions of dollars wasted, the project unfortunately was closed.